# redirect command executed along with output shell

Tags: linux, shell, shell-scripting, unix-shell

I would like to redirect the command executed along with the output to a file.

for example:
#ls >ls_out.txt

ls_out.txt should be something like :

---

ls

file1 fil2

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use "script" command:
Something like this:

```
localhost:test_sf user1$ ls
file1   file2   file3
localhost:test_sf user1$ script ls_out.txt  #starting script command ls_out.txt will contain output
Script started, output file is ls_out.txt
bash-3.2$ ls 
file1       file2       file3       ls_out.txt
bash-3.2$ exit
exit

Script done, output file is ls_out.txt
===================================================================================
localhost:test_sf user1$ cat ls_out.txt  #verify the contents now.
Script started on Wed Dec 18 12:05:23 2013
bash-3.2$ ls 
file1       file2       file3       ls_out.txt
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
```

You will just have to get rid off "bash-3.2$ exit exit" piece.

Comment: Superb..I never know that there is something like "script" command exists in Linux . I kind of overlooked your answer and didn't understand it properly.

Answer (score 6):

I use a function for this kind of thing:

```
echocmd() {
    echo "$@"
    "$@"
}
```

Then

```
$ echocmd ls -ltr > ls_out.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.. we can add this line too.  echo "`whoami`@`hostname`""$" "$@" in place of     echo "$@"